# Getting the coordinates of a specific ListViewItem relative to it's owning ListView

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listviewitem, adorner, adornerlayer

I'm trying to determine the physical coordinates (specifically I'm interested in the TOP and BOTTOM) of the container which represents the ListViewItem.

I have a reference to the ListViewItem via:

```
 ListViewItem item = ((ListView)AdornedElement).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(idx) as ListViewItem;
 ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(item);
```

I now need to take the item and figure out what it's top and bottom values are relative to the entire listview.  This is for showing a dragline indicator during a drag drop.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For someone who this may help in the future.  I figured this out (literally right after I posted)

```
    Point pointTransformToVisual = lvItem.TransformToVisual((Visual)theListView.Parent).Transform(new Point());

    Rect boundsRect = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(lvItem);
    boundsRect.Offset(transform.X, transform.Y);
```